# MySQL Error "Too many connections"

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I am using MySQL 5.0 for a site that is hosted by GoDaddy (linux).

I was doing some testing on my web app, and suddenly I noticed that the pages were refreshing really slowly. Finally, after a long wait, I got to a page that said something along the lines of "MySQL Error, Too many connections...", and it pointed to my config.php file which connects to the database.

It has just been me connecting to the database, no other users. On each of my pages, I include the config.php file at the top, and close the mysql connection at the end of the page. There may be several queries in between. I fear that I am not closing mysql connections enough (mysql_close()).

However, when I try to close them after running a query, I receive connection errors on the page. My pages are PHP and HTML. When I try to close a query, it seems that the next one won't connect. Would I have to include config.php again after the close in order to connect?

This error scared me because in 2 weeks, about 84 people start using this web application.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is some pseudo-code of my page:

```
 require_once('../scripts/config.php');

 <?php
    mysql_query..

    if(this button is pressed){
       mysql_query...
    }
    if(this button is pressed){
       mysql_query...
    }
    if(this button is pressed){
       mysql_query...
    }
 ?>
 some html..
 ..
 ..
 ..
 ..
 <?php
   another mysql_query...
 ?>
 some more html..
 ..
 ..
 <?php mysql_close(); ?>
```

I figured that this way, each time the page opens, the connection opens, and then the connection closes when the page is done loading. Then, the connection opens again when someone clicks a button on the page, and so on...

EDIT:

Okay, so I just got off the phone with GoDaddy. Apparently, with my Economy Package, I'm limited to 50 connections at a time. While my issue today happened with only me accessing the site, they said that they were having some server problems earlier. However, seeing as how I am going to have 84 users for my web app, I should probably upgrade to "Deluxe", which allows for 100 connections at a time. On a given day, there may be around 30 users accessing my site at a time, so I think the 100 would be a safer bet. Do you guys agree?

Comment: It may seem crazy, but try putting some kind of counter on your connection method to see if it's REALLY only being called once per page load. I had a similar problem where I was actually creating a new connection for every query without realizing it. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: @Mike B great suggestion, i will certainly try this.

Comment: @Mike B Okay, I added some code to my config.php file to write "INITIATED" to a file. I then clicked on 12 links within the site, and I got 12 "INITIATED" in the file...So it seems that a connection is initiated on each page load, as I expected. BUT, I noticed in my config.php that I had:

     $connect=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
     $connect_sting=mysql_select_db($dbname);

     mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

Which would open up two connections each time...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Shared-hosting providers generally allow a pretty small amount of simultaneous connections for the same user.

What your code does is :

- open a connection to the MySQL server
- do it's stuff (generating the page)
- close the connection at the end of the page.

The last step, when done at the end of the page is not **mandatory** : (quoting [`mysql_close`](http://php.net/mysql_close)'s manual) :

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually
>   necessary, as non-persistent open
>   links are automatically closed at the
>   end of the script's execution.

But note you probably shouldn't use persistent connections anyway...

Two tips :

- use `mysql_connect` insead of `mysql_pconnect` *(already OK for you)*
- Set the fourth parameter of mysql_connect to false *(already OK for you, as it's the default value)* : (quoting the manual) :

> If a second call is made to
>   mysql_connect()  with the same
>   arguments, no new link will be
>   established, but instead, the link
>   identifier of the already opened link
>   will be returned.
>
> The new_link 
>   parameter modifies this behavior and
>   makes mysql_connect() always open a
>   new link, even if mysql_connect() was
>   called before with the same
>   parameters.

---

What could cause the problem, then ?

Maybe you are trying to access several pages in parallel *(using multiple tabs in your browser, for instance)*, which will simulate several users using the website at the same time ?

If you have many users using the site at the same time and the code between `mysql_connect` and the closing of the connection takes lots of time, it will mean many connections being opened at the same time... And you'll reach the limit **:-(**

Still, as you are the only user of the application, considering you have up to 200 simultaneous connections allowed, there is something odd going on...

---

Well, thinking about "*too many connections*" and "`max_connections`"...

If I remember correctly, `max_connections` does not limit the number of connections **you** can open to the MySQL Server, but the **total number of connections** that can bo opened to that server, **by anyone connecting to it**.

Quoting MySQL's documentation on [Too many connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/too-many-connections.html) :

> If you get a Too many connections
>   error when you try to connect to the
>   mysqld  server, this means that all
>   available connections are in use by
>   other clients.
>
> The number of connections allowed is
>   controlled by the max_connections
>   system variable. Its default value is
>   100. If you need to support more connections, you should set a larger
>   value for this variable.

So, actually, the problem might not come from you nor your code *(which looks fine, actually)* : it might "just" be that you are not the only one trying to connect to that MySQL server *(remember, "shared hosting")*, and that there are too many people using it at the same time...

... And **if I'm right and it's that**, there's nothing you can do to solve the problem : as long as there are too many databases / users on that server and that `max_connection` is set to 200, you will continue suffering...

As a sidenote : before going back to GoDaddy asking them about that, it would be nice if someone could validate what I just said ^^

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough response! I was afraid that it could be something out of my control...

I'm glad to hear that my code is fine, but I was wondering if it would help any to create a mysql wrapper class that would connect to the db, run a query, and then close the connection? I decided I might try that out but, based on your response, it seems like closing the mysql connections may not be the issue...

Comment: I just posted an EDIT containing my conversation with GoDaddy.

Comment: Upgrading this way for only 84 users seems/feels a bit overkill to me (84 users is not that much ; tons of websites have more users than that, and don't have that kind of problem)... If they were having problems with their server, you should wait a bit to see how things are, now

Answer (score 3):

I had about 18 months of dealing with this (http://ianchanning.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/18-months-of-dealing-with-a-mysql-too-many-connections-error/)

The solutions I had (that would apply to you) in the end were:

1. tune the database according to [MySQLTuner](http://mysqltuner.com/).
2. defragment the tables weekly based on this [post](http://blog.barfoo.org/2008/09/19/defragmenting-all-fragmented-myisam-tables/)

Defragmenting bash script from the post:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of all fragmented tables
FRAGMENTED_TABLES="$( mysql -e `use information_schema; SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') AND
Data_free > 0` | grep -v '^+' | sed 's,t,.,' )"

for fragment in $FRAGMENTED_TABLES; do
  database="$( echo $fragment | cut -d. -f1 )"
  table="$( echo $fragment | cut -d. -f2 )"
  [ $fragment != "TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME" ] && mysql -e "USE $database;
  OPTIMIZE TABLE $table;" > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Comment: your nr1 link is a 404. was this the resource? https://raw.github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl

Comment: @JPHellemons Thanks, I've fixed the link - mysqltuner.com does redirect to the one you've mentioned. I've left it as mysqltuner.com in case the redirect gets changed again

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not using persistent connections. This is usually a bad idea..

If you've got that .. At the very most you will need to support just as much connections as you have apache processes. Are you able to change the max_connections setting?

Comment: I'm not using persistent connections. I cannot modify the max_connections setting but, according to GoDaddy:

"We allow up to 200 simultaneous connections per MySQL user."

Comment: If you don't have more than 200 Apache process, it would verify (like other posters mentioned) that you're not creating more than 1 connection per request.

Answer (score 2):

Are you completely sure that the database server is completely dedicated to you?

Log on to the datbase as root and use "SHOW PROCESSLIST" to see who's connected. Ideally hook this into your monitoring system to view how many connections there are over time and alert if there are too many.

The maximum database connections can be configured in my.cnf, but watch out for running out of memory or address space.

Comment: @MarkR Unfortunately, I cannot do this. I am using GoDaddy's Linux Hosting, so I don't have a dedicated or virtual server, so I cannot log in as root...

Answer (score 2):

If you have shell access, use netstat to see how many sockets are opened to your database and where they come from.

On Linux, type:

```
netstat -n -a |grep 3306
```

On windows, type:

```
netstat -n -a |findstr 3306
```

Comment: I was able to do that, however I have no idea how to interpret the results (as to come to any meaningful conclusions). I posted them at the following link, would you mind taking a look? I was logged into my site when I did the netstat...

http://www.cs.scranton.edu/~behrk2/netstat_results.rtf

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution could one of these, i came across this in a MCQA test, even i did not understood which one is right!

Set this in my.cnf "set-variable=max_connections=200"

Execute the command "SET GLOBALmax_connections = 200"

Use always mysql_connect() function in order to connect to the mysql server

Use always mysql_pconnect() function in order to connect to the mysql server

Answer (score 1):

Followings are possible solutions:

**1)** Increase the max connection setting by setting the global variable in mysql.

```
set global max_connection=200;
```

**Note:** It will increase the server load.

**2)** Empty your connection pool as below :

`FLUSH HOSTS;`

**3)** check your processList and kill specific processlist if you don't want any of them.

You may refer this :-

[article link](http://www.easysolutionweb.com/sql-pl-sql/how-to-deal-with-too-many-connections-error-in-mysql?stack)