# Is it possible to list MySQL Server closed connections?

Tags: mysql

To list active connections we do:

```
show processlist;
```

What to do to list old closed connections?

Comment: That information is hardly going to be stored. What do you need this for?

Comment: I have created a php that created 'too many connections' yesterday and I need to do heavy inspection about the issue

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Maybe the top answer to this question gives some pointers what to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202322/mysql-error-too-many-connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could obtain [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/173203/how-to-list-mysql-server-closed-connections) nice answer from [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that there's nothing provided by MySQL to list old connections.  But you could capture the data flowing between your web front end and your database:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 -w /tmp/mysql.cap tcp port 3306
```

run your PHP, have it fail, stop the capture and use Wireshark to see exactly what was going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1 but apache runs on the same server as mysqld and it does not connect using sockets.