# NodeJs function inside forEach loop need to complete before go to next item

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, foreach

I have a Nodejs script, where it's detail look like below :

1) it requests to API to get a list of city, it will get JSON array. using this array, I do looping using `forEach`.

2) at each iteration (2nd loop), I do request again to API to get details (about 100 rows) and insert it into `mysql` database.

my question, how to make the function inside the first loop (**where to get the list of city**) wait to complete before going to next item (city). I want to make a loop sequential with delay.

my source code :

```
const request = require('request');
var moment = require('moment');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var a = moment('2019-04-01');
var b = moment('2019-04-06');
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));

function timer(ms) {
 return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'user1',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'local'
});

async function getURL(id_city,dates) {

    var url = 'https://localhost/api/format/json/schedule/city/'+id_city+'/date/'+dates;    
    request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }
      // console.log(body.status);
      var item1 = body.schedule.data.item1;
      var item2 = body.schedule.data.item2;

      connection.connect();
      connection.query('INSERT INTO schedule (city,item1,item2) values ("'+id_city+'","'+task1+'", "'+task2+'")', function (error, results, fields) {
         if (error) throw error;
      });
      // connection.end();    
    });
}


async function getDate(id_city)
{
    var end;
    for (var m = moment(a); m.isBefore(b); m.add(1, 'days')) {
        getURL(id_city,m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        await timer(1000); //making delay           
    }
}

async function main () {    
    var url = 'https://localhost/api/format/json/list_city';
    connection.connect();
    request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }

          var list_city = body.city; //this is an array
          var counter = 0;
          list_city.forEach(function(city){
              getDate(city.id, function(){

              });//i need this to complete before go to next city

          });
    });//end request url
}

main();
```

my expectation (sequential) :

```
city1
insert item a done...
insert item b done...
city2
insert item a done...
insert item b done...
insert item c done...
city3
...
```

Comment: You need to have one async function with proper await  sequence.

Comment: @ShubhDixit could you give any example ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both `request` and `mysql` you can use the `Promise` supported package namely: `request-promise` and `mysql2`. To guarantee sequential execution, you can then do:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

// then in your getURL function
async function getURL(id_city,dates) {

  var url = 'https://localhost/api/format/json/schedule/city/'+id_city+'/date/'+dates;
  const body = await rp(url, { json: true })
  const item1 = body.schedule.data.item1;
  const item2 = body.schedule.data.item2;

  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost', user: 'root', database: 'test'});
  const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('INSERT INTO schedule (city,item1,item2) values ("'+id_city+'","'+task1+'", "'+task2+'")');
}

// One await in getDate should do
async function getDate(id_city) {
  var end;
  for (var m = moment(a); m.isBefore(b); m.add(1, 'days')) {
    await getURL(id_city,m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  }
}
```

For handling error with `async/await`:

```
try {
  const body = await rp(url, { json: true })
} catch (e) {
  // handle erorr
  console.error(e);
  // or rethrow error: throw e
}
```

For efficiency you could use `mysql connection pool` like:

```
// myPool.js
const mysql = require('mysql2');

// create pool
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host:'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'test',
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0
});
// now get a Promise wrapped instance of that pool
const promisePool = pool.promise();

module.exports = () => promisePool; 

// Then in your getURL
const getPool = require('./myPool');
async function getURL(id_city,dates) {
  ...

  const pool = await getPool();
  const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute('INSERT INTO schedule (city,item1,item2) values ("'+id_city+'","'+task1+'", "'+task2+'")');
  ...
```

Also consider using `prepared` statement.

```
connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = ? AND `age` > ?', ['Morty', 14]);
```

Comment: when using mysql pool, i got error `TypeError: pool.promise is not a function`, How to solve this ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, should have mentioned in the answer the required import. Updated answer, for that to work you need to change import to `mysql = require('mysql2')`

Comment: thanks, btw how about error `sqlMessage: 'Too many connections`, any idea to solve this ? btw, i have using mysql pool...

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202322/mysql-error-too-many-connections, maybe you specified too many connections in pool? If you've found the answer you sought, mark the specific answer accepted (:

Comment: If you're using hosting environment, that may be too much depending on how much the environment allow for example. check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331032/mysql-error-1040-too-many-connection/34176072 If none solves the issue, you're better off posting new question with relevant information

Comment: now i get this error too often : `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: id_city is not defined` i cant predict and find root cause of this error. any idea ?

Comment: you've to `try/catch` wherever you use `await` in example shown above in `handling error` block

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar You are mentioned "for efficiency" but you are re-creating pool at the beginngn of getURL function which defeats the whole purpose of pool

Comment: @AndreySidorov, you're right, I didn't notice that. Thanks, updating my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop instead of `forEach`, and on each iteration, `await` the call of `getDate`, so that one `getDate` call always finishes before it gets called again:

```
for (let i = 0; i < list_city.length; i++) {
  await getDate(city[i]);
  await timer(100); // this will put a delay of at least 100ms between each call
}
```

Make sure to make the containing function `async` for this to work.

Note that since `getDate` returns a Promise, it probably shouldn't accept a callback - either chain `await`s or `then`s on to the end instead.

Comment: you can also use `for (const city of list_city)` for more succinct code